# I keep getting numpy.ndarray is not callable and i dont see what's wrong

Tags: python, numpy

```
def sec_order_1(t,a0,k): # 2a -> c
    return a0/(a0*k*t+1)
a0=10; k=1
t=np.array(time_seconds)
data=np.array(concentrations_mM)
calc_y=sec_order_1(t,a0,k)
plt.plot(t, data,'o', label='data')
plt.plot(t, calc_y, label='model, k: %g' %k)
plt.xlabel('time / seconds'); plt.ylabel('concentration_mM')
plt.legend(); plt.show()

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
f=sec_order_1(t,a0,k)
xdata = t
ydata=data/a0
p0=1
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f,xdata, ydata,p0=p0)
print(popt,pcov)
ydata = a0*f(xdata,*popt) 
plt.plot(t,data,'o')
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, label='Best-fit k: %.3f ± %.3f / week' % (popt[0], perr))
```

This code is attempting to make a line of best fit. I have tried many solutions I have seen other people use for this error but i need more specific help. If any of my code is weird I apologize, I am just attempting to use the template our professor gave us but his did not have this issue despite me trying my best to copy his.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Hard it is to know which is caussing error without knowing where the error is. Your code it's not self-containing. so every try would be a blind guess

Comment: `sec_order_1` returns an array, `f=sec_order_1(t,a0,k)` -> `ydata = a0*f(xdata,*popt)`. An array is not callable. What did you expect to do here?

Comment: My first blind guess would be: after plot you assing `ydata = ..` there you call `f(xdata,*popt)` But `f` should be an array, cause you assigned it as return of your func

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `numpy.ndarray is not callable` because somewhere in your code, you are calling a `numpy.ndarray`

Your function `sec_order_1` returns a numpy array.

In your second block of code, you assign the numpy array returned by `sec_order_1` to the variable `f`. Later on, you do `f(xdata,*popt)` which is the source of your greviance.